# How to take pictures in the rain with a digital camera, so that lens doesn't get damaged?

Tags: photography

I do a lot of trekking and visiting waterfalls. 
I have a digital camera, however, I cannot take pictures in these wet environments (rain, waterfalls, etc.) because I do not feel comfortable risking my camera from getting water damage.

*Is there a Do-It-Yourself waterproof case that will allow me take pictures in these environments?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily create a waterproof case for your Camera (Digital Camera, Phone Camera, everything except for DSLR witch you did not mention you had so I am making an assumption.

Based on my assumption, One common method of waterproof DIY is to use a food preserver (Vacuum's the air out then seals it.) This method will work with your camera, phone, anything you need. The beauty of it is, if your use this method for your phone, the audio still can be heard, the touch screen still works, etc... so its 100% adaptable and usable.

If you are using DSLR, you will need to consider a complete enclosure since the lens connects to the base unit.

**Here is the Vacuum I am referencing**

[image: Food Vacuum]

Comment: Thanx for the answer Hector , can u post the picture of food preserver sealing the lens..Because i dint get which kind of food preserver u meant..!

Comment: @skanda93 No problem, I will update it now!

Comment: Thank you for the image @Hector .. Now i understood what you meant . Though we can take pictures by using that technique we need to compromise with the picture quality .

Comment: I don't see how this would work for a camera...  Those vacuum bags are clear on one side and textured on the other.  The textured side will prevent you from seeing the screen, and the clear side is going to degrade photo quality one way or another.  Great idea for a phone or MP3 player or something, but not a camera.